# Cellpadding isn't working

Tags: email, html-email, padding

I have padding around the table holding the copy, but the text reads to the edges when I test it.

It's supposed to look like the image attached. I'm not sure why it's not showing up.

I tried adding `padding` in inline style, `cellpadding`, both. It's still not working.

```
<body style="background:#FFF; color:#858585">
<div id="preheader" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:#878787; color:transparent; height:0; width:0; font-size:0px;">Current Brands and Products</div>
<div class="container" style="Margin:0 auto; max-width:600px;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="container" style="Margin:0 auto; max-width:600px;">
        <tr class="bronto">
            <td height="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bronto">
            <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">Is this email not displaying correctly? <a href="%%!message_url%%" style="font:bold 100%/6mm Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:none;">Try the web version</a>.</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#D2CAB3" height="30px"><div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 103px;"><img class="desktop" src="http://www.kravet.com/emails/George-Ruch-Products/top.jpg" alt="Top" style="max-width:600px; display: block;" /></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="imgWidth" align="left" valign="middle" width="58" bgcolor="#D2CAB3"><div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 934px;"><img class="desktop" src="http://www.kravet.com/emails/George-Ruch-Products/left.jpg" alt="Left" style="max-width:58px; display: block;" /></div></td>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <table cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="padding:0px 20px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 25px"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/emails/img/kravet-inc-logo-2017.gif" alt="Kravet Inc." style="max-width:435px;"></td>
                                </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:italic 175% Times New Roman, 'serif'; color:#56565b; letter-spacing:1px; line-height: 100%;" class="smaller">To all Valued Kravet Inc. customers</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">In order to provide complete clarity, we currently sell and service the following brands and products:</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><span style="font:bold 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%; text-decoration: underline;">Kravet</span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Gaston Y Daniela<br />
                                                Laura Ashley<br />
                                                Lizzo<br />
                                                Luxe Light and Home</span></td>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Ralph Lauren Home<br />
                                                The Shade Store<br />
                                                Winfield Thybony<br />
                                                Andrew Martin</span></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><span style="font:bold 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%; text-decoration: underline;">Lee Jofa</span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Blithfield<br />
                                                Bunny Williams Home<br />
                                                Cole &amp; Son<br />
                                                GP &amp; J Baker<br />
                                                Groundworks</span></td>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Holland &amp; Co.<br />
                                                Lincrusta<br />
                                                MacRae<br />
                                                Mulberry Home<br />
                                                Threads</span></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><span style="font:bold 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%; text-decoration: underline;">Brunschwig &amp; Fils</span></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Creations-Metaphores<br />
                                                Jagtar<br />
                                                Le Crin<br />
                                                Mally Skok Design</span></td>

                                                <td width="50%" class="half"><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">
                                                Matthews &amp; Parker<br />
                                                Thatchers<br />
                                                Tisserant Art &amp; Style<br />
                                                Verel De Belval</span></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">Please add this information to your existing vendor contact information by brand.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">Also, if you have any questions regarding our products and services please ask.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">Most importantly, thank you for your business and continued support of Kravet Inc.</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">We are at your service!</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">Sincerely,</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="font:bold 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;">George and Holly Ruch<br />
Kravet Inc.<br /></span>
<span style="font:normal 80% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#56565b; line-height:21px; line-height: 150%;"><a href="mailto:George.Ruch@kravet.com">George.Ruch@kravet.com</a><br />
Cell: 336-210-6474<br />
<a href="mailto:Holly.Ruch@Kravet.com">Holly.Ruch@Kravet.com</a><br />
Cell: 336-772-2666</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="20"></td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="imgWidth" align="right" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D2CAB3" width="58"><div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 934px;"><img class="desktop" src="http://www.kravet.com/emails/George-Ruch-Products/right.jpg" alt="Right" style="max-width:58px; display: block;" /></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" height="30px;" bgcolor="#D2CAB3"><div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 100px;"><img class="desktop" src="http://www.kravet.com/emails/George-Ruch-Products/btm.jpg" alt="Bottom" style="max-width:600px; display: block;" /></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="20"></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="318" valign="middle" class="onefamily">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td style="border-top:1px dotted #868686"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="264"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/one-family-email.gif" alt="One Family. Ninety-Nine Years" style="width:264px !important"></td>
                    <td width="18" valign="middle" class="onefamily">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" width="100%">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                <td style="border-top:1px dotted #868686"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 150% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585"><span style="font:normal 87.5%/4mm Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">@</span>kravetinc</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
                  <tr>
                        <td><a  href="http://www.instagram.com/kravetinc?utm_source=instagram&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/instagram.gif" alt="Instagram" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a  href="http://www.facebook.com/kravetinc?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/facebook.gif" alt="Facebook" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a  href="http://www.pinterest.com/kravet?utm_source=pinterest&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/pinterest.gif" alt="Pinterest" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a  href="http://www.twitter.com/kravet?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/twitter.gif" alt="Twitter" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a  href="http://www.houzz.com/pro/kravet/kravet?utm_source=houzz&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/houzz.gif" alt="Houzz" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><a  href="http://match.kravet.com/?utm_source=matchicon&utm_medium=email&utm_content=imagelink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products"><img src="http://www.kravet.com/style-spotlight/match2.gif" alt="Kravet Match" border="0" style="border:none; width:100%; max-width:50px" /></a></td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td height="10"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td align="center"><a href="http://www.e-designtrade.com?utm_source=edesigntrade&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products" style="font:normal 112.5% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585;">e-designtrade.com</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td height="40"></td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
            <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; line-height: 1.5;"><a href="http://www.kravet.com?utm_source=kravetwebsite&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; line-height: 1.5;">KRAVET&reg; INC</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://www.kravet.com/services/contact?utm_source=contact&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; line-height: 1.5;">CONTACT US</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="http://www.kravet.com/about%20us/privacy%20policy?utm_source=privacy&utm_medium=email&utm_content=textlink&utm_campaign=George-Ruch-Products" style="font:bold 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; line-height: 1.5;">PRIVACY POLICY</a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><span style="font:bold 75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585">Exclusively Available Through Interior Designers</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="40"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bronto">
            <td align="center"><span style="font: normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #858585; line-height: 1.5;" xml="lang">This email was sent to %%!contact_email%% by %%!account_organization%%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bronto">
            <td align="center"><span style="font: normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #858585; line-height: 1.5;" xml="lang">%%!account_address1%% | %%!account_city%%, %%!account_state%% %%!account_zip%%</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bronto">
            <td align="center"><span style="font:normal 68.75% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; line-height: 1.5;"><a href="%%!forward_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline; line-height: 1.5;">Forward to a friend</a> | <a href="%%!manage_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline; line-height: 1.5;">Manage Preferences</a> | <a href="%%!unsubscribe_url%%" style="font:normal 100% Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#858585; text-decoration:underline; line-height: 1.5;">Unsubscribe</a></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="40"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: my table]

Comment: where's your main `<table>`?

Comment: your inner table already has cell padding of 20. Try removing that and then add to others if you want.

Comment: Syfer, I already tried having only cellpadding or padding. Neither worked.

Comment: Updated to have the main div / table.

Answer (score 0):

You should removed all of the rows with a just single fixed height td, as these essentially are spacer areas to negate the need for padding.

```
    <tr>
        <td height="40"></td>
    </tr>
```

I'd also recommend sticking with standard inline padding over using cellpadding, as you'll have more control over the spacing. Setting cellpadding="20" a table means 20 padding is applied to every cell within that table.